# Prestashop installation problem - MySQL support is not enabled

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, installation, prestashop

I am trying to get Prestashop 1.4.1.1 installed locally. In the 2nd step - "System Compatybility" I keep getting an error saying that MySQL support is not enabled.

Also when I'm trying to import my client's site to my local machine I get the error: HTTP 500 and I'm assuming this may be because of the above (they are using the same version of Prestashop 1.4.1.1)

I've already commented out lines in php.ini file (I'm using PHP7):

```
extension=mysqli
extension=pdo_mysql
```

and checked and commented out the directory for ext file:

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

But this didn't solve my problem and I keep getting the same error

Is there anything else I should do to enable MySQL support?

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop 1.4 is out of date, it can not work with PHP 7 without deep modification of the code source.

At least install the version 1.6 who is not too much different of the 1.4 version and compatible with PHP 7.

But my advice is to use the 1.7 version after upgrade your version to 1.5 , 1.6 first.